# Out of memory error - Talend insert/update job

Tags: talend

I have a job as shown below. tmysqlinput_1 has rows that need to be updated/inserted in the tmysqloutput. tmysqlinput_2 is the same table as tmysqloutput. I join tmysqlinput_1 and tmysqlinput_2 in tmap through an inner join. However, when I put some test rows in tmysqinput_1 which I know will lead to the update branch, and run the job,  I get the error **Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded**

May I know why this does not happen for insert but happening for update?

[image: Job with update and insert branches]

Thanks 
Rathi

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the amount of data which is being downloaded from the database into your Talend job.

Since the processing is standard ETL processing, all data will be loaded into the Talend job, consuming memory. Depending on your row layout (amount of rows x amount of columns x datatypes of columns) this will take more or less RAM.

So in this case I suppose that the lookup is very costly and will result in running out of memory.

One way in solving is to change the processing to ELT components which set the complete processing into the database and not in the Talend job.

Another way would be, depending on the use case, using "Insert Ignore" or "Insert or Update" in the `tMySQLOutput`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this join on disk by selecting the temp option true in tmap for lookup setting and give a temp directry path in tmap setting

Comment: i tried same scenario, what i believe now is you dont need to join destination table with source table and update/insert the destination table. As it's a inner join with destination table, that means you are matching only those keys which are present in destination. so u can direct put your source table as main flow without any join with destination table and in output component just select insert/update option.

Comment: This method you have suggested was my first design. Because it was so slow, I had to venture out to find other solutions.

Comment: I think you have to select to use disk and there will be a parameter to control the no of records in memory i.e. default 2 million , change it to 200K.

Answer (score -2):

just add -Xmx1024M to Talend=> Run/Degug